# Xcode 8 will not download all profiles

Tags: xcode8

I had xcode 7.3.1 installed and yesterday downloaded and installed the production release of xcode 8.  I click download profiles in my account area and not all will download. I tried deleting all in Finder. I tried clicking the Download button individually.

How do I get all profiles to download?

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Same problem here, regenerating all profiles didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up regenerating all my provisioning profiles which has worked for me. Quite strange...I don't know why that changed anything.

edit: on further investigation this is still happening...sometimes all our provisioning profiles aren't even showing up in the list to download let alone some getting stuck.